# React boilerplate - page is blank after build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-boilerplate

Im using almost the most famous react boilerplate (after react-create-app):

https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate

Started the project like a half year ago. Tried to build it recently, however when I start the `index.html` file after building, an error shows up in the console:

`ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` - main.js bundle.

Was searching how to fix it for a while, then found a solution to add `.` before `/` inside `webpack.base.babel.js` file:

```
entry: options.entry,
output: Object.assign({
   path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
   publicPath: './',    //    <-------------- here
}, options.output)
```

Rebuilded the  bundle, the error is gone but the blank page is displayed.

**No errors** in the console. No errors when compiling the dynamic files, no errors after `yarn install` aswell as after `yarn start`. Everything seems to be just right but still the blank page appears...

Looking forward for any kind of help how to deal with it.

**Important**: I downloaded the latest version of this boilerplate and builded. It didn't work without the `dot`. However, it works with the `./`.

Comment: I tried react-boilerplate recently, and have the same problem. Have you solved this yet?

Comment: @EasonPI ye I had problem with `i18n`, I removed it by accident and thats why i had these issues. `module.hot.accept(['./i18n', 'containers/App'], () => {` (u need `i18n`)